# How i can group by enum c# list

Tags: c#, list

i have a list of custom object and i want to group the object with the enum they have in the custom object.

how i can do this in c#

i want to new list of the existing list by their enum means each list have a difference enum

```
   public struct xyz
        {
            public int ID;
            public string Name;
            public ClassType Type;
        }
```

i want to make a new list who have a different enum

Comment: Are you asking how to group in general? Because an enum is nothing special.

Comment: There's no enum in your new sample code

Comment: What does "i want to make a new list who have a different enum" mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sample code was there in the earlier version of your post, don't know why you took it out, anyway - you can use `GroupBy()` on  the List of your custom type:

```
enum CustEnum
{
    A=1,
    B,
    C
}

class CustomType
{
    public CustEnum xyz { get; set; }
}


...

List<CustomType> customTypes = ...    
var groupedList = customTypes.GroupBy(x => x.xyz).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try using Linq's groupBy method. I shall post some code to help you understand

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj1 = new MyClass(MyEnum.One);
            var obj2 = new MyClass(MyEnum.Two);
            var obj3 = new MyClass(MyEnum.One);
            var obj4 = new MyClass(MyEnum.Two);

            var lst = new List<MyClass>() {obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4};
            var studentQuery2 =
                from obj in lst
                group obj by obj.enumr8 into g
                    select new { g.Key, g };

        foreach (var obj in groupedLists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Key);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();    


        }
    }


    class MyClass
    {
        public MyEnum enumr8;

        public MyClass(MyEnum enumr8_Val)
        {
            this.enumr8 = enumr8_Val;  
        }
    }

    enum MyEnum
    { 
        One=1,
        Two
    }
```

Comment: I'd stop at the grouping, not throw them into anonymous objects.  The grouping you get back is all that is needed.